# CSS position text vertically relative to image inside hyperlink

Tags: html, css

I'm having two problems with this CSS code, and I'm needing a second set of eyes to help me look at it.

1.I'm trying to move my text up a bit while not moving the image inside of my navbar. Everything should look centered in the navbar, but the text seems to be offset and I'm not sure how to fix it. My only understanding of fixing vertical alignment is through padding, but that would also impact the image.

2. I'm trying to make the hover-over effect dynamic and resize according to window height, but I seem to be having trouble accomplishing this.

**Codepin:** https://codepen.io/dansbyt/pen/ZEWvZwJ

**CSS in question:**

```
.navbar{
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 56px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #5B7042;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #3F5328}
  .navbar_links{
    margin-left: 22%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 78%}
  .navbar_links a{
    padding: 2%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Archivo', sans-serif;
    font-size: x-large;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;}
  .navbar_links a:hover {background-color: #3F5328}
```

Comment: for align text

<a href="../index.php"><img style="width:30%" src="http://mrdansby.com/projects/dash_icon.png"><span> Dash</span></a>

and then add .navbar_links span{
  position:relative;
  bottom:5px;
}

Comment: You're AWESOME! Thank you so much. Do you know how to fix problem #2 by chance?

Comment: thanks, about #2 i didn't get what you want exactly

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
.navbar {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 56px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #5B7042;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #3F5328;
}

.navbar_links {
    margin-left: 22%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 78%;
}

.navbar_links a {
    line-height: 56px;
    display: flex;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Archivo', sans-serif;
    font-size: x-large;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.navbar_links a:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
}

p {
    margin-block-start: 0;
    margin-block-end: 0;
}
```

```
<div class="navbar">
  <div id="computer" class="navbar_links">
    <a href="../index.php"><img src="http://mrdansby.com/projects/dash_icon.png"> Dash</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That accomplishes the text alignment, but then the image will not be part of the button :( https://imgur.com/a/UvTczq4

Comment: If you add a transparent background to your image, it will look better, as its a PNG. But anyway, I would not use an image as an icon. Better use icons from font-awesome, for isntance. The integration is simple and there are tons of available icons to use (https://fontawesome.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but that's not what I'm aiming to do. I'm trying to get the text to correctly vertically align

Answer (score 0):

add span to text and style to it and use rem instead % for navbar_links a padding

```css
.navbar{
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 56px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #5B7042;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #3F5328}
  .navbar_links{
    margin-left: 22%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 78%}
  .navbar_links a{
    padding: 1.2rem;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Archivo', sans-serif;
    font-size: x-large;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;}
 .navbar_links span{ position:relative; bottom:5px; }
  .navbar_links a:hover {background-color: #3F5328}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div id="computer" class="navbar_links">
    <a href="../index.php"><img style="width:30%" src="http://mrdansby.com/projects/dash_icon.png"> <span>Dash</span></a>
```